# How to have different color for alternate row for MUI v4 Table?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Below are my code. I tried setting the tableRowRoot in the style.js but the row background color for alternate row did not change. I hope to just set the root for table row so I do not need to add any class or logic to the rows etc. Hope you guys can show me the correct way to do this.

```
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

export default makeStyles((theme) => ({
  tableRowRoot: {
    '&:nth-of-type(odd)': {
      backgroundColor: theme.palette.action.hover,
    },
  },
}));
```

```
import useStyles from './styles';

const Event = ({ pendingEvents, handleUpdateEvent }) => {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <Container className={classes.content}>
      <div className={classes.toolbar} />
      <Typography className={classes.title} variant='h3' gutterBottom>
        List of Pending Request
      </Typography>
      <TableContainer component={Paper}>
        <Table className={classes.table} aria-label='simple table'>
          <TableHead>
            <TableRow>
              <TableCell className={classes.th}>Email</TableCell>
              <TableCell className={classes.th}>Name</TableCell>
              <TableCell className={classes.th}>Reason</TableCell>
              <TableCell className={classes.th}>Start Date</TableCell>
              <TableCell className={classes.th}>End Date</TableCell>
              <TableCell className={classes.th}>Approve / Reject</TableCell>
            </TableRow>
          </TableHead>
          <TableBody>
            {pendingEvents.map((event) => (
              <TableRow key={event.id}>
                <TableCell component='th' scope='row'>
                  {event.email}
                </TableCell>
                <TableCell>{event.name}</TableCell>
                <TableCell>{event.reason}</TableCell>
                <TableCell>{new Date(event.start).toDateString()}</TableCell>
                <TableCell>{new Date(event.end).toDateString()}</TableCell>
                <TableCell>
                  <IconButton
                    aria-label='Approve'
                    color='inherit'
                    onClick={() => handleUpdateEvent(event, 'approved')}
                  >
                    <ThumbUpIcon color='primary' />
                  </IconButton>
                  <IconButton
                    aria-label='Reject'
                    color='inherit'
                    onClick={() => handleUpdateEvent(event, 'rejected')}
                  >
                    <ThumbDownIcon color='secondary' />
                  </IconButton>
                </TableCell>
              </TableRow>
            ))}
          </TableBody>
        </Table>
      </TableContainer>
    </Container>
  );
};

export default Event;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a `tableRowRoot` rule, but I don't see you set the className in the `TableRow` to apply the custom styles:

```
<TableRow key={event.id} className={classes.tableRowRoot} /* <------- Add this */>
```

From the [docs](https://v4.mui.com/components/tables/#customized-tables), you can also use `withStyles` to create a styled component from the original one:

```
const StyledTableRow = withStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    '&:nth-of-type(odd)': {
      backgroundColor: theme.palette.action.hover,
    },
  },
}))(TableRow);
```

```
<TableBody>
  {pendingEvents.map((event) => (
    <StyledTableRow key={event.id}>
      {...}
    </StyledTableRow>
  ))}
</TableBody>
```

Comment: Is there a way to tie the style to the TableRow without using the className={classes.tableRowRoot}?

Comment: @JasonTan why don't you want to use `className` if you're using `makeStyles`?

Comment: @JasonTan I updated the answer using `withStyles` as an alternative.

Comment: I'm trying to see whether there is a way to use the root .MuiTableRow-root Styles applied to the root element at this link: [link]https://v4.mui.com/api/table-row/#tablerow-api

Comment: @JasonTan the class name `.MuiTableRow-root` is mapped to the rule name `root` if you use `withStyles`, if you're using `makeStyles`, declare any styles you want and pass to the `TableRow` className which is the styles of the root component (same as `withStyles`).

Comment: @JasonTan in your `makeStyles` code `&` refers the root class name `.MuiTableRow-root` FYI.

Comment: I do not know how to put the withStyles into makeStyles as my makeStyles is a separate js file.

Comment: @JasonTan you either use `makeStyles` or `withStyles` to create custom styles for your components, you cannot use both. Use `withStyles` if you want to create a whole new component with custom styles. Use `makeStyles` if you want to reuse the styles and create a set of classnames that you can pass to any components.

Comment: If I were to use withStyles, how do I place it as a separate file and call it in the file that contain the table component?

Comment: @JasonTan you can reuse the component by putting `StyledTableRow` in another file and import it in your main file.

Comment: @JasonTan you can see [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/69751510-how-to-have-different-color-for-alternate-row-for-mui-v4-table-3w2oy?file=/demo.js) codesandbox demo for reference.

Comment: ```export const StyledTableRow = withStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    '&:nth-of-type(odd)': {
      backgroundColor: theme.palette.action.hover,
    },
  },
}))(TableRow);```